# Can a vacuum make a turbulent flow laminar?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, vacuum, turbulence

When a vacuum is generated next to a turbulence, does the flow towards the vacuum become laminar? Imagine a vacuum cleaner tube is put next to turbulent air movement, does the "suction" change the turbulent air flow to a laminar one?

Comment: Draw a picture, how would the air avoid being sucked up into the vacuum, it's an interesting question but show what you mean in practice.

Comment: Google Northrop X 21 for a variation of your idea about boundary layer control

Comment: Many people have a misconception of what it means to have flow laminar, but more particularly turbulent, as defined in the strict sense. The two regimes of flow are delineated by the Reynolds Number - a dimensionless number that involves fluid viscosity and velocity, and some characteristic length defining the boundary in which the flow occurs. The presence of eddies or vorticity does not necessarily mean the flow is turbulent in a strict sense. 'Suction' is just another name for negative or less positive pressure and which creates the potential that leads to flow.

Answer (score 2):

Just adding a sink somewhere will not change the nature of the flow. The flow is characterized by characteristic lengths and velocities, and material properties. These can be combined to give the Reynolds number, which is indicative of the likeliness of transition to turbulence. If you add a sink, you will only possibly modify the characteristic velocity difference, but it may be difficult to decrease it significantly without altering the function of whatever device you study.

Then, in very specific cases, you can reduce velocity difference: this has been applied to boundary layers in [boundary layer suction (link)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_layer_suction) techniques. Basically, by sucking air at the surface of a wing, you reduce the difference of velocity between the bulk of air flow and air close to the wing (zero without suction). As you can understand, each geometry and flow parameters need a separate study to determine whether this will work: so there is no principle saying that vacuum will reduce turbulence.

Comment: My thoughts are as follows: When a vacuum is generated, the pressure difference get balanced in a way that the surrounding air molecules get pushed into the low pressure zone along the shortest path, which means they move translational. From a macroscopic view that should be a laminar flow (what happens when the molecules reach the vacuum is another matter).

Comment: Turbulence arises not when laminar flow is not "possible", but when it is not stable. So a reasoning like "I could devise laminar flow lines for the setup" does not allow to determine whether there'll be turbulence of not.